# List value by group by sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below

```
Id | PriceCardId | Days
1  |   1         | 2
2  |   1         | 4
3  |   1         | 5
4  |   1         | 6
5  |   1         | 3
6  |   2         | 5
7  |   2         | 3
8  |   3         | 6
```

How to write SQL query to get all PriceCardId has Day contain

```
List<int> days
Example days = [2,4,5,6], with data as above result is 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more clear about the results you want?

Comment: Best if you provide an example of the expected result set. For instance, do you want all the CardId's that have a Day value in the list ?  Or have a full match with the days list ?

Comment: @AmirPelled i want full match with the days list

Comment: so you only want PriceCardIds which has records for all the days in your list? What about if the ID also matches other days as well? Is that OK? Please be precise and cover all the scenarios. Also, what have you tried so far? This isn't just a free do-my-work service.

Comment: @RyanGadsdon I want all PriceCardId that have a Day value FULL MATCH with the days list,

Comment: @tungck Using capitals doesn't make your question any clearer...

Comment: like everyone keeps saying, before you can say to us "full match", you have to define what you actually mean by that phrase. It has no definitive technical meaning, so you need to tell us what the rules are. Judging by the answers so far and your comments on them, no-one understands what you really want. You keep saying that the suggested queries fail, but then you don't explain clearly what a successful result would be, so its no surprise that people keep getting it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
select pricecardid
from t
where day in (2, 4, 5, 6)
group by pricecardid
having count(*) = 4;  -- the number of days you are looking for
```

This assumes no duplicates in your table.  If there are duplicates, use `having count(distinct day)` instead of `count(*)`.

Note:  You can phrase this as:

```
with d as (
      select v.dy
      from values ( (2), (4), (5), (6) ) v(dy)
     )
select pricecardid
from t 
where day in (select d.dy from d)
group by pricecardid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT PriceCardId 
FROM [My_Table] 
WHERE [Day] IN(2,4,5,6)
GROUP BY PriceCardId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Day])=4
```

Comment: No, I want as
SELECT PriceCardId FROM [Your_Table] WHERE List[Day] contains (2,4,5,6).

Comment: @tungck, Are you try my answer? Is it not ok?

Comment: This is actually exactly what you requested.  Select the PriceCardId's that have matching Day's for all the provided list.  If it's not, then I suggest you rewrite the question with more examples.